# kubernetes Autoscaler - Cannot obtain loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I'm trying to define an Horizontal Pod Autoscaler for two Kubernetes services.

The Autoscaler strategy relies in 3 metrics:

1. cpu
2. pubsub.googleapis.com|subscription|num_undelivered_messages
3. loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count

*CPU* and *num_undelivered_messages* are correctly obtained, but no matter what i do, i cannot get the *request_count* metric.

The first service is a backend service (Service A), and the other (Service B) is an API that uses an Ingress to manage the external access to the service.

The Autoscaling strategy is based on Google documentation: [Autoscaling Deployments with External Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/external-metrics-autoscaling).

For service A, the following defines the metrics used for Autoscaling:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: ServiceA
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: ServiceA
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      targetAverageUtilization: 80
  - external:
      metricName: pubsub.googleapis.com|subscription|num_undelivered_messages
      metricSelector:
        matchLabels:
          resource.labels.subscription_id: subscription_id
      targetAverageValue: 100
    type: External
```

For service B, the following defines the metrics used for Autoscaling:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: ServiceB
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: ServiceB
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      targetAverageUtilization: 80
  - external:
      metricName: loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count
      metricSelector:
        matchLabels:
          resource.labels.forwarding_rule_name: k8s-fws-default-serviceb--3a908157de956ba7
      targetAverageValue: 100
    type: External
```

As defined in the above article, the metrics server is running, and the metrics server adapter is deployed:

```
$ kubectl get apiservices |egrep metrics
v1beta1.custom.metrics.k8s.io          custom-metrics/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter   True        2h
v1beta1.external.metrics.k8s.io        custom-metrics/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter   True        2h
v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io                 kube-system/metrics-server                          True        2h
v1beta2.custom.metrics.k8s.io          custom-metrics/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter   True        2h
```

For service A, all metrics, CPU and num_undelivered_messages, are correctly obtained:

```
$ kubectl get hpa ServiceA
NAME       REFERENCE             TARGETS               MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
ServiceA   Deployment/ServiceA   0/100 (avg), 1%/80%   1         3         1          127m
```

For service B, HPA cannot obtain the Request Count:

```
$ kubectl get hpa ServiceB
NAME                REFERENCE    TARGETS                              MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
ServiceB   Deployment/ServiceB   <unknown>/100 (avg), <unknown>/80%   1         3         1          129m
```

When accessing the Ingress, i get this warning:

> unable to get external metric default/loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count/&LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{resource.labels.forwarding_rule_name: k8s-fws-default-serviceb--3a908157de956ba7,},MatchExpressions:[],}: no metrics returned from external metrics API

The **metricSelector** for the forwarding-rule is correct, as confirmed when describing the ingress (only the relevant information is show):

```
$ kubectl describe ingress serviceb
Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule:  k8s-fws-default-serviceb--3a908157de956ba7
```

I've tried to use a different metric selector, for example, using *url_map_name*, to no avail, i've got a similar error.

I've followed the exact guidelines on Google Documentation, and checked with a few online tutorials that refer the exact same process, but i haven't been able to understand what i'm missing.
I'm probably lacking some configuration, or some specific detail, but i cannot find it documented anywhere.

What am i missing, that explains why i'm not being able to obtain the *loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count* metric?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the metric that you're defining isn't available in the [External Metrics API](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/external-metrics-api.md#api). To find out what's going on, you can inspect the External Metrics API directly:

```
kubectl get --raw="/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" | jq
```

Is the *loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count* metric reported in the output?

You can then dig deeper by making requests [of the following form](http:///apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/%3Cnamespace_name%3E/%3Cmetric_name%3E?labelSelector=%3Cselector%3E):

```
kubectl get --raw="/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/<namespace_name>/<metric_name>?labelSelector=<selector>" | jq
```

And see what's returned given your metric name and a specific metric selector.

These are precisely the requests that the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler also makes at runtime. By replicating them manually, you should be able to pinpoint the source of the problem.

---

**Comments about additional information:**

**1)** 83m is the Kubernetes way of writing 0.083 (read as 83 "milli-units").

**2)** In your HorizontalPodAutoscaler definition, you use a `targetAverageValue`. So, if there exist multiple targets with this metric, the HPA calculates their average. So, 83m might be an average of multiple targets. To make sure, you use only the metric of a single target, you can use the `targetValue` field (see [API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#externalmetricsource-v2beta1-autoscaling)).

**3)** Not sure why the `items: []` array in the API response is empty. The documentation mentions that after sampling, the data is not visible for 210 seconds... You could try making the API request when the HPA is not running.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you very much for your detailed response.

When using the metricSelector to select the specific *forwarding_rule_name*, we need to use the exact *forwarding_rule_name* as defined by the ingress:

```
metricSelector:
    matchLabels:
    resource.labels.forwarding_rule_name: k8s-fws-default-serviceb--3a908157de956ba7
```

```
$ kubectl describe ingress

Name: serviceb
...

Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule:  k8s-fws-default-serviceb--9bfb478c0886702d
  ...
  kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http:             false
  kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name:  static-ip
```

The problem, is that the suffix of the *forwarding_rule_name* (3a908157de956ba7) changes for every deployment, and is created dynamically on Ingress creation:

- k8s-fws-default-serviceb--**3a908157de956ba7**

We have a fully automated deployment using Helm, and, as such, when the HPA is created, we don't know what the *forwarding_rule_name* will be.

And, it seems that the *matchLabels* does not accept regular expressions, or else we would simply do something like:

```
metricSelector:
    matchLabels:
    resource.labels.forwarding_rule_name: k8s-fws-default-serviceb--*
```

I've tried several approaches, all without success:

1. Use Annotations to force the *forwarding_rule_name*
2. Use a different machLabel, as *backend_target_name*
3. Obtain the *forwarding_rule_name* using a command, so i can insert it later in the yaml file.

**Use Annotations to force the *forwarding_rule_name*:**

When creating the ingress, i can use specific annotations to change the default behavior, or define specific values, for example, on Ingress.yaml:

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: static-ip
```

I tried to use the https-forwarding-rule annotation to force a specific "static" name, but this didn't work:

```
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule: some_name


  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule: some_name
```

**Use a different machLabel, as *backend_target_name***

```
metricSelector:
        matchLabels:
          resource.labels.backend_target_name: serviceb
```

Also failed.

**Obtain the *forwarding_rule_name* using a command**

When executing the following command, i get the list of Forwarding Rules, but for all the clusters. And according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/), is not possible to filter by cluster:

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules list
```

```
NAME                                        P_ADDRESS   IP_PROTOCOL  TARGET
k8s-fws-default-serviceb--4e1c268b39df8462  xx          TCP          k8s-tps-default-serviceb--4e1c268b39df8462
k8s-fws-default-serviceb--9bfb478c0886702d  xx          TCP          k8s-tps-default-serviceb--9bfb478c0886702d
```

Is there any way to allow me to select the resource i need, in order to get the Requests count metric?

Comment: I created an issue on GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver GitHub: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/issues/296, but unfortunately, it hasn't been assigned to anyone yet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems everything was OK with my code, but, there is a time delay (aprox. 10m), before the *request_count* metric is available. After this period, the metric is now computed and available:

```
$ kubectl get hpa ServiceB
NAME                REFERENCE    TARGETS                MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
ServiceB   Deployment/ServiceB   83m/100 (avg), 1%/80%  1         3         1          18m
```

Now, regarding the *loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count* metric, i'm not understanding how its being presented. What does **83m** means?

According to Google documentation for [Load balancing metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-loadbalancing):

> https/request_bytes_count Request bytes
>
> DELTA, INT64, By
>
> GA
>
> The number of requests served by HTTP/S load balancer. Sampled every 60 
>   seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 210 seconds.

According to [Metric Details](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/metrics-details):

> In a DELTA metric, each data point represents the change in a value
>   over the time interval. For example, the number of service requests
>   received since the previous measurement would be a delta metric.

I've made one single request to the service, so i was expecting a value of **1**, and i can't understand what the **83m** means.

Another possibility, could be that i'm not using the correct metric.
I've selected the *loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count* metric, assuming it would provide the number of requests that were executed by the service, via the loadbalancer.

Isn't exactly this information that the *loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count* metric provides?

Regarding the above comment, when executing:

```
kubectl get --raw="/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pubsub.googleapis.com|subscription|num_undelivered_messages" | jq
```

i get the correct data:

> ... 
>   {
>         "metricName": "pubsub.googleapis.com|subscription|num_undelivered_messages",
>         "metricLabels": {
>           "resource.labels.project_id": "project-id",
>           "resource.labels.subscription_id": "subscription_id",
>           "resource.type": "pubsub_subscription"
>         },
>         "timestamp": "2019-10-22T15:39:58Z",
>         "value": "4"
>       }
>   ...

but, when executing:

```
kubectl get --raw="/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count" | jq
```

i get nothing back:

> {   "kind": "ExternalMetricValueList",   "apiVersion":
>   "external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",   "metadata": {
>       "selfLink": >"/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/loadbalancing.googleapis.com%7Chttps%7Crequest_count"
>   },   "items": [] }

Comment: See comments in previous answer. Also, for comprehensibility, I would rather add the additional information as an edit to the question rather than as an answer.